# How to enable TYPO3 non-admin to administer backend users

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 6.x, is there a recommendable way to allow non-admin BE users to create and modify other BE users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option that has been in TYPO3 since long time ago is to set up an **action** (requires "sys_action" to be installed - it's a system extension that is shipped with the TYPO3 source).

In the root (uid=0) of the TYPO3 installation you create an action and set the type to "*Create Backend User*" while assigning this action to a particular group of users - they will have access to this action using the action menu (upon clicking on an icon) at the top of the backend interface.

While the creation of new users works fine, there is a **problem** with editing of users - any **user can edit only users that he himself created**.

Comment: Would you use that in a current setup (is it still ok to use nowadays), and are the rights ok (created user shouldn't be able to do more than the user who created him)? About the last issue I wouldn't worry, this would be fine

Comment: Yes, I personally did use that in the past - though I don't know if it still works fine under TYPO3 6.x. As for the rights - you create a dummy user record that the action is going to use as a template for new accounts and you also set which user groups can this user be assigned - so just make sure that a group of users having this action available can only assign the same group when creating a new user.